# Infinity loop with generating random numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a script that creates random mathematical problems (simple questions). The problem is that there seems to be an infinite loop, and I can't figure out where or how my script can run without this part of the code.

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/GyJKwP?editors=1010

```
var arr = [];
 var lastArr = [];


while(lastArr.length<122){
    arr.push('<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'=');
  lastArr=removeDuplicates(arr);

}
document.write(lastArr.join(' '));

alert(arr.length);


function removeDuplicates(arr){
    let unique_array = []
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
            unique_array.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return unique_array
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is not an inifite loop, but a very looooooong loop. You are removing duplicates, but there can only be up to a 121 different options. So it can only end once it finds all random numbers between 1 and 121. This is a very small chance. So it takes a long time to get there. I believe to calculate the actual chance you would need to do a markov chain

Comment: Your problem is that theoretically an infinite loop is possible when you're relying on random numbers, code pen is just trying to prevent you doing something stupid by stopping the execution

Comment: Also, look into  using a set. It is designed to store unique values

Comment: Thank guys, now i understand the problem, but how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The line `Math.round(Math.random() * 10)` will give you 11 possible outcomes (from `0` to `10`). That means there are 11*11 non-duplicates `lastArr` can hold.

As mentioned in the comments, it does not only take a long time for every possibility to occur, it is also impossible for `lastArr` to be longer than `121` (11*11), which means your loop cannot end, due to the condition `while(lastArr.length<122)`.

Besides that there are better ways to achieve the desired result, changing your code to *this* will make it work:

```
var arr = [];
var lastArr = [];


while(lastArr.length<121){  // Here I change 122 to 121
    arr.push('<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'=');
  lastArr=removeDuplicates(arr);

}
document.write(lastArr.join(' '));

alert(arr.length);


function removeDuplicates(arr){
    let unique_array = []
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
            unique_array.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return unique_array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working snippet without any infinity loop.

```js
var arr = [];
while(arr.length < 121){
  var randValue = '<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'='
    arr.push();
    // Check duplicate elements before push
  if ( arr.indexOf(randValue) == -1 ) arr.push(randValue);
}
document.write(arr.join(' '));
alert(arr.length);
```

Comment: For random numbers up to 10, this takes an average of 650 "attempts" to fill the array. For numbers up to 100, the average rockets up to 100,046 "attempts". This entire approach is incredibly inefficient and there is a non-zero probability that the browser will kill the process for taking too long before it's done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to shuffle every possible outcome of adding two numbers from 0 to 10. Why not do that, rather than your attempt of "throw missiles into pidgeonholes and hope for the best"?

```js
function generateArray(maxA, maxB) {
  var arr = [],
    a, b;
  for (a = 0; a <= maxA; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b <= maxB; b++) {
      arr.push([a, b]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function shuffleArray(arr) {
  // simple Fisher-Yates shuffle, modifies original array
  var l = arr.length,
    i, j, t;
  for (i = l - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
  }
}

function outputArray(arr) {
  var i, l = arr.length;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    document.write("<br />" + arr[i][0] + " + " + arr[i][1] + " = ");
  }
}

var arr = generateArray(10, 10);
shuffleArray(arr);
outputArray(arr);
```